# Find the average value from the previous row and the current row for a same department id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 employees with the same departments. i wanted to find the average of their salaries based on the previous rows.

For example

```
Employee_id  department_id salary   avg(salary)
101             1           5000      5000
102             1           10000     7500
103             1           15000     10000
```

This is like for department id as 1 with first salary we find the average as 5000 for employee id 101 and for the same department id as 1 for the employee id as 102 , we find the average for the 2 values grouped by department id. 
Hence 
average is (10000+5000) /2 = 7500

But for the employee id as 103, department id is 1 and is grouped with all the above three values of amount.
Hence,
average of salary is (10000+5000+15000)/3 = 10000

The requirement is i have been asked to use query_partition_clause and order_by_clause.

Hence i tried as follows,

```
 select  avg(salary) OVER (partition by department_id ORDER BY department_id ) salary, department_id, salary from employee
```

But i am always getting the values by considering the department of 3 data values.

Henceforth can somebody help on this resolution?

Many Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY salary` (or `ORDER BY employee_id`) rather than `ORDER BY department_id`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employees ( Employee_id, department_id, salary ) AS
SELECT 101, 1,  5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 1, 10000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 1, 15000 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT e.*,
       AVG( salary ) OVER ( PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY salary ) AS avg_salary
FROM   employees e
```

**Output**:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID | SALARY | AVG_SALARY
----------: | ------------: | -----: | ---------:
        101 |             1 |   5000 |       5000
        102 |             1 |  10000 |       7500
        103 |             1 |  15000 |      10000
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f22641851d7e69a0483a8844329eb0d2)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, 
       DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       SALARY, 
       (SELECT AVG(SALARY) 
          FROM EMPLOYEES B 
         WHERE B.EMPLOYEE_ID <= A.EMPLOYEE_ID) AVG_SALARY
  FROM EMPLOYEES A
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID, 
          DEPARTMENT_ID, 
          SALARY
```

A sub query can be done in the query itself by filtering the employee ID. I hope I have helped with something.